# RichTextEditor inside ScrollView is not going up along with Keyboard in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard, scrollview, rich-text-editor

My View hierarchies are

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var demoHtml: String = "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<50) {_ in
                    Text("Editor needs improvement")
                }


                VStack {
                    MarkupEditorView(html: $demoHtml)
                }
                .frame(minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 200)

                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6.0)
                        .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1.0)
                )
                .padding()
            }

            Button("Tap", action: {})
                .background(.green)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm facing few serious issue, while trying to meet the requirement

1. I'm using `MarkupEditorView` library to support RichTextEnvironment, the problem that `MarkupEditorView` **is not scrolling up along with keyboard on focus** when using inside `ScrollView`
2. On View load **MarkupEditorKeyboard** auto comes on focus without tapping on `MarkupEditorView`
3. Last and most serious problem is `Done Button` out side of ScrollView move above the keyboard that I don't want, As per my requirement `Done Button` should always be stick on bottom without any movement.

Comment: Ever find an answer for this?